# What's the fastest way to open LogCat view?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

Most of the times I run a Project I need to open/maximize LogCat and then minimize it. 
Usually it takes a few clicks with the mouse.

Click the LogCat icon on the Debug perspective *ctrl+M* to maximize it and then click the minimize icon.

Wonder if there is a faster way, hope without the need to click the mouse.

Comment: What IDE are you talking about? Eclipse or Intellij?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Window -> Preferences.
Then go to General -> Keys.
Find the entry "Show View (View: Logcat)"
Go to Binding and hit a key (such as F10).

Personally, I use two screens for developing. Main Window on the main screen and Logcat, File Explorer and Console on the second one.

Comment: Two screens is the best solution since LogCat View is so important.
For now I'll stay with *ctrl+L* to open LogCat view and *ctrl+M* to maximize it.

Comment: You can as well make a custom key shortcut as I explained above. It should acutally remember the window size when you close it so you dont need to maximize it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you already have the LogCat view open. But, when you want to maximize it, its a pain to double click it every time.

Solution:
Use Ctrl+F7 to shift between the views like "LogCat", "Console", "Editor" etc. Then when you are at particular view, just use Ctrl+M to maximize the view in full screen. 
I think you will like some of the Shortcuts mentioned here: http://www.rapidsnail.com/Developer/topic/2012/76/27/60320/ask-next-eclipse-the-commonly-used-shortcut-key.aspx

Comment: Yes its a pain to double click. _Ctrl+M_ works for maximizing but if I don't click the LogCat window can't use it again to minimize. 
I'm not sure if you understand exactly what I said about the minimize part. LogVat View is open and maximized and I see let's say a simple Log.V message I added to the code but I can't minimize it with _Ctrl+M_ unless I click on the View.

Ctrl+F7 is quite similar to the solution @Toast provided.

Answer (score 0):

Window -> Show View -> Other -> Android -> LogCat

Answer (score 0):

I personally think Eclipse is not the best place to watch logcat (it is already as heavy as it gets by default, and you put more into it...).

So, I recommend good old command line (Linux):

```
$ adb logcat -v time
```

I have created a logcat colorizer to help distinguish the important stuff:
https://bitbucket.org/brunobraga/logcat-colorize

Answer (score 0):

- Press Shift Twice
- Type logcat
- Press Enter

Answer (score 0):

In your Android Studio:

View > Tool Windows > Logcat from the menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+A to get a list of all actions (searchable) then search for "Logcat".